# Simple computation in numpy

Tags: numpy

I have numpy array like this `a = [-- -- -- 1.90 2.91 1.91 2.92]`

I need to find % of values more than 2, so here it is 50%.
How to get the same in easy way? also, why len(a) gives 7 (instead of 4)?

Comment: There are 7 elements in the array, even though only 4 of them are numbers.

Comment: is there anyway to fetch number of numeric element?

Comment: Where does the '--' come from?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.ma as ma

a = ma.array([0, 1, 2, 1.90, 2.91, 1.91, 2.92])
for i in range(3):
    a[i] = ma.masked
print(a)
print(np.sum(a>2)/((len(a) - ma.count_masked(a))))
```

The last line prints 0.5 which is your 50%. It subtracted from the total length of your array (7) the number of masked elements (3) which you see as the three "--" in the output you posted.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, you can simply use

```
a = np.array([...])
threshold = 2.0
fraction_higher = (a > threshold).sum() / len(a)  # in [0, 1)
percentage_higher = fraction_higher * 100
```

Answer (score -1):

The array contains 7 elements, being 3 of them masked. This code emulates the test case, generating a [masked array](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/maskedarray.generic.html) as well:

```
# generate the test case: a masked array
a = np.ma.array([-1, -1, -1, 1.90, 2.91, 1.91, 2.92], mask=[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0])

# check its format
print(a)
[-- -- -- 1.9 2.91 1.91 2.92]

#print the output
print(a[a>2].count() / a.count())
0.5
```

Comment: Nice, I didn't know the `count()` function. Why downvote?

Comment: Thanks! Didn't get the downvote either... sometimes, it happens! :)